# Running "rails test" is throwing Bad file descriptor (Errno::EBADF) error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium-webdriver, rubygems

I am using rails 6. I followed the tutorial in "https://www.learnenough.com/ruby-on-rails-4th-edition-tutorial" to develop a sample rails application. However, when I try to run "rails test", it is throwing **Bad file descriptor (Errno::EBADF) error**.

My GEM file:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.5.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.0'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5'
# Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
gem 'webpacker', '~> 4.0'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.2', require: false

group :development, :test do

  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do 
# Use mysql2 as the database for Active Record
  gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.5.2'
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of web drivers to run system tests with browsers
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '~> 1.1', '>= 1.1.4'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

The error that I got when running "rails test" is

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 6349
Run options: --seed 17984

# Running:

.Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
        28: from -e:1:in `<main>'
        27: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        26: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        28: from -e:1:in `<main>'
        25: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
        27: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        24: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:139:in `run'
        26: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        23: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:139:in `loop'
        25: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
        22: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:145:in `block in run'
        24: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:139:in `run'
        23: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:139:in `loop'
        21: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:175:in `serve'
        22: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:145:in `block in run'
        20: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:175:in `fork'
        21: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:175:in `serve'
        19: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:63:in `block in autorun'
        20: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:175:in `fork'
        18: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:133:in `run'
        19: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:63:in `block in autorun'
        17: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `start'
Traceback (most recent call last):
        16: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `map'
        15: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `each'
        18: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:133:in `run'
        14: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `times'
        17: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `start'
        16: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `map'
        15: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `each'
        13: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:75:in `block in start'
        14: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `times'
        13: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:75:in `block in start'
        12: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:75:in `fork'
        11: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:95:in `block (2 levels) in start'
        10: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:1139:in `method_missing'
        28: from -e:1:in `<main>'
         9: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:1159:in `with_friend'
        12: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:75:in `fork'
         8: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:1140:in `block in method_missing'
         7: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:1214:in `open'
        27: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
         6: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:1214:in `synchronize'
        11: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:95:in `block (2 levels) in start'
        10: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:1139:in `method_missing'
         9: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:1159:in `with_friend'
         8: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:1140:in `block in method_missing'
         7: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:1214:in `open'
         6: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:1214:in `synchronize'
         5: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:1217:in `block in open'
         4: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:1217:in `each'
        26: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
         3: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:1219:in `block (2 levels) in open'
        25: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
         5: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:1217:in `block in open'
         4: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:1217:in `each'
        24: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:139:in `run'
         2: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:1263:in `alive?'
         3: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:1219:in `block (2 levels) in open'
        23: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:139:in `loop'
         2: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:1263:in `alive?'
        22: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:145:in `block in run'
         1: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:1006:in `alive?'
        21: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:175:in `serve'
/Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:1006:in `wait_readable'  20: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:175:in `fork'
:        1: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:1006:in `alive?'
Bad file descriptor/Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:1006:in `wait_readable':  (Bad file descriptor      19: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:63:in `block in autorun'
 (Errno::EBADFErrno::EBADF      18: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:133:in `run'
        17: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `start'
)
)
        16: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `map'
        15: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `each'
        14: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `times'
        13: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:75:in `block in start'
        12: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:75:in `fork'
        11: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:95:in `block (2 levels) in start'
        10: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:1139:in `method_missing'
         9: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:1159:in `with_friTraceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
end'
Traceback (most recent call last):
         8: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:1140:in `block in method_missing'
         7: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:1214:in `open'
         6: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:1214:in `synchronize'
        28: from -e:1:in `<main>'
         5: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:1217:in `block in open'
        28: from -e:1:in `<main>'
        27: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
         4: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:1217:in `each'
        28: from -e:1:in `<main>'
        26: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
         3: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:1219:in `block (2 levels) in open'
        27: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
         2: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:1263:in `alive?'
        27: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
         1: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:1006:in `alive?'
/Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:1006:in `wait_readable'  26: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
:       25: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
        25: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
        26: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        24: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:139:in `run'
Bad file descriptor (   23: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:139:in `loop'
        25: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
        22: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:145:in `block in run'
Errno::EBADF    24: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:139:in `run'
        21: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:175:in `serve'
        23: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:139:in `loop'
)
        20: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:175:in `fork'
        22: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:145:in `block in run'
        19: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:63:in `block in autorun'
        24: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:139:in `run'
        21: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:175:in `serve'
        18: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:133:in `run'
        20: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:175:in `fork'
        17: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `start'
        19: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:63:in `block in autorun'
        23: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:139:in `loop'
        16: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `map'
        18: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:133:in `run'
        15: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `each'
        17: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `start'
        14: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `times'
        16: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `map'
        13: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:75:in `block in start'
        15: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `each'
        14: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `times'
        13: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:75:in `block in start'
        12: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:75:in `fork'
        11: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:95:in `block (2 levels) in start'
        10: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:1139:in `method_missing'
         9: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:1159:in `with_friend'
         8: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:1140:in `block in method_missing'
         7: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:1214:in `open'
        22: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:145:in `block in run'
         6: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:1214:in `synchronize'
        21: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:175:in `serve'
         5: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:1217:in `block in open'
        20: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:175:in `fork'
         4: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:1217:in `each'
        19: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:63:in `block in autorun'
         3: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:1219:in `block (2 levels) in open'
        18: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:133:in `run'
        12: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:75:in `fork'
        11: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:95:in `block (2 levels) in start'
        10: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:1139:in `method_missing'
         9: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:1159:in `with_friend'
         8: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:1140:in `block in method_missing'
         7: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:1214:in `open'
         6: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:1214:in `synchronize'
         2: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:1263:in `alive?'
         5: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:1217:in `block in open'
         4: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:1217:in `each'
         3: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:1219:in `block (2 levels) in open'
         2: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:1263:in `alive?'
         1: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:1006:in `alive?'
/Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:1006:in `wait_readable': Bad file descriptor (Errno::EBADF)
         1: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:1006:in `alive?'
/Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:1006:in `wait_readable': Bad file descriptor (Errno::EBADF)
        17: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `start'
        16: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `map'
        15: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `each'
        14: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:74:in `times'
        13: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:75:in `block in start'
        12: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:75:in `fork'
        11: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:95:in `block (2 levels) in start'
        10: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:1139:in `method_missing'
         9: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:1159:in `with_friend'
         8: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:1140:in `block in method_missing'
         7: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:1214:in `open'
         6: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:1214:in `synchronize'
         5: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:1217:in `block in open'
         4: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:1217:in `each'
         3: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:1219:in `block (2 levels) in open'
         2: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:1263:in `alive?'
         1: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:1006:in `alive?'
/Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/drb/drb.rb:1006:in `wait_readable': Bad file descriptor (Errno::EBADF)
Traceback (most recent call last):
        5: from -e:1:in `<main>'
        4: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        3: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        2: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:63:in `block in autorun'
        1: from /Users/deepak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:140:in `run'
/Users/deepak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/testing/parallelization.rb:118:in `shutdown': Queue not empty, but all workers have finished. This probably means that a worker crashed and 8 tests were missed. (RuntimeError)
```

Note: I have set the default environment as Test and then ran my application.

Comment: I had to update my `puma` gem from `4.x` to `5.x` and then removed `preload_app!` from `config/puma.rb`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `/test/test_helper.rb` file, remove parallel testing. Your file should look something like:

```rb
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require_relative '../config/environment'
require 'rails/test_help'

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Run tests in parallel with specified workers
  # OLD: parallelize(workers: :number_of_processors)  <--
  parallelize(workers: 1) # i.e don't run tests in parallel via forked processes
  # OR just comment the line above out completely <--

  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
  fixtures :all

  # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...
end
```

Comment: We're having trouble with this too, but we're trying to make parallel testing work, because it's supposed to. We get the Bad file descriptor (Errno::EBADF) after a handful of tests are run if we run it against mysql 8.0, but mysql 5.7 doesn't exhibit the issue. Not sure that is a mysql version difference, a homebrew-default-mysql-configuration issue, or a mysql2 gem compilation issue.

Comment: I've opened an issue with Rails for this issue: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/41176